# How to cast result back to generic list (using linq to object)?

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Dim a As New List(Of EntityTableRow)
            a = myTable1.TableRows

            Dim lFinal2 = (From el In a Group el By Key = New With {Key el.Description, Key el.Activity, Key el.ServiceGroup, Key el.SubServiceGroup, Key el.ResourceGroup, Key el.Country, Key el.DCN, Key el.Workforce, Key el.RateType, Key el.LoadType} _
                              Into Group Select New With { _
                              .PageNum = "", _
                              .Description = Key.Description, _
                              .Activity = Key.Activity, _
                              .MonthCosts = (From k In Group.SelectMany(Function(g) g.MonthCosts.Keys).Distinct() _
                                            Select New With {.Month = k, .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(g) _
                                        If(g.MonthCosts.ContainsKey(k), g.MonthCosts(k), 0))}).ToDictionary(Function(i) i.Month, Function(i) i.Sum)})
```

I am not able to cast the above result back into the original object form from the below code:

```
    Dim myTable1_grouped As New EntityDATATable(Of EntityTableRow) 
    myTable1_grouped.TableRows = CType(lFinal2, List(Of EntityTableRow))
```

original class is like below. The class has a number of more string properties, which I have omitted for this snippet. All those properties also are using in the grouping in above linq code.:

```
Public Class EntityTableRow
    Public PageNum As Integer
    Public Description As String
    Public Activity As String
    .....
    .....
    .....
    Public MonthCosts As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
End Class
```

The error I am getting is:

System.InvalidCastException was caught
  Message="Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[VB$AnonymousType_1`2[VB$AnonymousType_0`10[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Addin.EntityTableRow]],VB$AnonymousType_2`35[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.Double]]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Addin.EntityTableRow]'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you have to do there:

Set your class name when creating the results:

```
Into Group Select New EntityTableRow With { _
```

instead of:

```
Into Group Select New With { _
```

And add `ToList()` to enumerate and get results into a `List<EntityTableRow>`:

```
myTable1_grouped.TableRows = CType(lFinal2.ToList(), List(Of EntityTableRow))
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I didn't know I could select a type of class itself!